# What is the correct way of re-assigning a derived object from its custom constructor

Tags: c++, oop

given following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  int a;
  A() : a(0) {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  int b;
  B(int b) : b(b) {}
  B() {}
};

int main()
{
  B new_b;
  new_b.b = 5;
  new_b.a = 4;
  std::cout << new_b.a << std::endl;
  new_b = B(2); // at this point I want to keep new_b.a
  std::cout << new_b.a << std::endl;
}
```

What is the correct way of achiving this? I know I could overload B's assignment operator and only take over new_b.b here, but is this the proper way of keeping B.a's value?

Thanks for any help on this issue.

Kind Regards,
Steve

Comment: `static int a;` is one way, and drop the initialisation in the constructor. Might not be what you want, hence not a full answer. `new_b.setB(2);` might be more sensible.

Comment: Hi Bathsheba, first of all thanks for your comment. Yeah actually I think in my real code I should rather use a set function as you suggested, since acually Iam only interested in changing one property of the object, I just realized now :-) Thanks for this hint..

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int a;
    A() : a(0) {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int b;
    B(int b) : b(b) {}
    B() : b(0) {}
    B operator = (B ob) // using operator overloading, the = operator is overloaded
    {
        b = ob.b;
        return b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B new_b;
    new_b.b = 5;
    new_b.a = 4;
    std::cout << new_b.a << std::endl;

    new_b = B(2); /* Previously a new object of class B with parameterized constructor was made and copied to new_b which created a new object of class A everytime.
                  Now as the = operator is overloaded, it just copies the value(2) into new_b without creating a new object of class B or A thus the original value of A::a is preserved*/

    std::cout << new_b.a << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Hi this is my first time posting an answer, hope I was clear enough for you to understand, if you have a problem I'd be happy to help again